# Why does crash in Activity DOES NOT crash whole app - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm just starting with Android Developing (having some iOS development experience), and I'm pretty much appalled why if I "crash", only ONE activity crashes not whole application ?

I have created demo app (why only MyActivity3 crashes not whole app?)

http://youtu.be/Jo4oBMAsSew

Code to initiate MyActivity2:

```
Button goToActivity2Button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.goToActityButton);

final MyActivity2 self = this;
goToActivity2Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(self, MyActivity3.class);
           self.startActivity(activity3Intent);
       }
});
```

And crash in MyActivity3

```
Button goToActivity2Button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.crashTheAppButton);

goToActivity2Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String nullString = null;
        nullString.length();

    }
});
```

Comment: Remove `self` from `self.startActivity(activity3Intent)`. There is no need to use self in that.

Comment: Please, note the reason for downvoting. I'm just curious of the design decision made in AndroidOS.

Comment: Have you removed? `self` from `self.startActivity(activity3Intent)`?, also change `self` to `MainActivity2.this` in `Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(self, MyActivity3.class);`.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya What's wrong with using final self ?

Comment: No need of extra code. 
`Intent intent= new Intent(SouceActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);`
How `Intent` Works

Answer (score 0):

Because MyActivity2 isn't finished when you press the button. You started the intent to go in MyActivity3, you create MyActivity3 but MyActivity2 is still "in background". If you want to handle the Activity cycle, you have to override `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods.
Till you don't `finish()` an activity, it will remain opened.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also new in Android programming and have met with the same case countless times. If I'm not mistaken, each Activity is considered as a different thread. When a thread crushes, it doesn't mean that the whole program will crush, just the thread where the exception occured. That's why when an Activity crushes, if the exception wasn't a problem for previously opened Activities, the current Activity will crush and the previous one, which was running in the background, will become the running Activity. Generally, from what I've heard, you should make your app to end Activities on purrpose. Instead, it is better to let the OS handle the opening and closing of the Activities whatever way it considers to be the most optimal.

Comment: All activities are running in the same thread, called Main Thread.